# Microsoft Chatbot Framework returning HTTP status code InternalServerError for Facebook messenger

Tags: chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I've deployed *Microsoft Chatbot Framework* chatbot as a *Web App Bot*. It is working in emulator, it is working in *Test in Webchat* in Azure, but when I try to use it from *Facebook messsenger* I'm getting:

`There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError`

Is there a way how to get a more detail logs? I have *Application Insights* turned on, but still can't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a similar problem.  I quickly implemented NLOG (basic implementation is simple) in my bot and wrote all error logs and some addition events to a text log.  It was a huge help for me.

Hope this helps:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial